# Social buttons available on Central Admin but not on sites

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, social

The "I Like It" and "Tags and Notes" buttons are visible in my server's Central Administration ribbon. But only the latter is visible on my SharePoint site, and when a user clicks it, it allows only notes, not tags. The Social Tags and Note Board Ribbon Controls feature is already activated on the farm.

Answer (score 0):

Tags and note board feature in SharePoint 2010 depending on the Managed Meta Data service.

- Make sure the Managed Meta Data service is started and you can access it (go to central admin > service application and click on MMS).
- Also, Make sure MMS service is associated with the web application in the service connection.
- Sometime recycle the App pool for the MMS service application fix the issue.

Comment: The service is already running and already associated with the web application. As a test, I added the URL of the site collection as the content type hub's URL. I'll see if recycling the app pool works.